# (latex) Alignment in pst-tree

Tags: latex, pstricks

In this example, using `pst-tree` package:

```
\def\psedge{\ncangles[armA=.5, angleB=180, linearc=.2]}
\pstree[treemode=R, levelsep=3cm] {\Toval{ root }} {
  \Toval{ Tom }
  \Toval{ Cat }
  \Toval{ Very very very very very long entry }
  \Toval{ Jerry }
}
```

The output is ugly because the nodes are aligned by center, how can I make it align to the left?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Hi, how can I move this question to tex.stackexchange.com?

Comment: 谢继雷: At the moment, this actual move can't be done, but you can ask the same qn there and put a link here.  And in this case, that qn has already been asked.

Answer (score 0):

A nearly identical question was asked on tex.sx: [pstree: How can I force a tree node to one side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4250/pstree-how-can-i-force-a-tree-node-to-one-side), whose accepted answer says that putting in invisible nodes works.